# What to put in wordpress content views with civicrm dataprocessor join

Tags: wordpress, extension

I am stumped :) 
I have set up everything to search civicrm from front end of wordpress. I see on content views the civicrm section but have no idea what to put in to see the dataprocesses selection. Am I supposed to be seeing something else? Thanks[image: screenshot of content views]

Comment: Is it that I need the pro version of Content Views to be able to select from Data processors? Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the dataprocessor extension and set up a processor as defined in the instructions ?

Comment: See also this closed issue in the issue queue - the discussion may help you, https://github.com/agileware/content-views-civicrm-data-processor/issues/1

Comment: Good morning and thank you for sharing this promising solution. I wanted to know if you had found an answer to the issue raised above, as I'm struggling to integrate civicrm content on a WordPress website project. Being new to civicrm, I can't display the civicrm entry in Content View (like on Bendov screenshot). I followed the instructions in the [quick guide](https://github.com/agileware/content-views-civicrm-data-processor), but I am missing something: It says "format the title in the display settings -> title content", but I'm stuck at this step... I can't understand this instruction. I we